# javascript web page is not receiving notification in foreground mode, although receiving in background (only data messages)

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, vue.js, push-notification

I am using Vue js on client-side and node js on the backend side. I am sending data message and it is getting received by the client-side when the browser's tab is inactive. But when the tab is active, it doesn't receive notification.

Here is my code on client-side

```
      // Your web app's Firebase configuration
      var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "<apiKey>",
        authDomain: "<authDomain>",
        databaseURL: "<db>",
        projectId: "<projectId>",
        storageBucket: "<storageBucket>",
        messagingSenderId: "<senderId>",
        appId: "<appId>"
      };
      // Initialize Firebase
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      // Retrieve Firebase Messaging object.
      const messaging = firebase.messaging();
      messaging.usePublicVapidKey(
        "<KEY>"
      );
      messaging
        .requestPermission()
        .then(function() {
          retrieveToken();
          console.log("Notification permission granted.");
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log("Unable to get permission to notify. ", err);
        });
      function retrieveToken() {
        messaging
          .getToken()
          .then(deviceToken => {
            if (deviceToken) {
              console.log(deviceToken);
              messaging.onMessage(payload => {
                console.log("Message received. ", payload);
              });
            } else {
              console.log(
                "No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one."
              );
            }
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log("An error occurred while retrieving token. ", err);
          });
      }
      }
    </script>
```

And here is my server side code

```
var message = {
       data: {
         score: "850",
         time: "2:45"
       },
       token: registrationToken
    };

  // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
  // registration token.
    admin
      .messaging()
      .send(message)
      .then(response => {
        // Response is a message ID string.
        console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
      });
```